# Trying to install and initialize jhub and ebd kernels with mamba command. Says EnvironmentNameNotFound: could not find conda environment

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

## Background context

I'm currently trying to install an openSAR distribution in Ubuntu, by following the installation instructive available at [INSTALLATION.md in GitHub](https://github.com/EarthBigData/openSAR/blob/master/INSTALLATION.md). When trying to create jhub and ebd environments, it says `EnvironmentNameNotFound: could not find conda environment`. **I am doing this to run Jupyter Lab server working on my local webbrowser.**

So far, i have obtained and installed the indicated Python packages, the free Miniconda python distribution and mamba. I have cloned the git repository in my VirtualMachine.

For the **Setup the conda environments** part, it indicates the following:

> To work with the code and notebooks, you need to establish virtual environments within Anaconda. The advantage of virtual environments is the complete separation of different dependencies for projects. We provide environment files to create kernels in the conda environment to work with. You can obtain these files in the openSAR/yaml folder

The kernels to be set are the jhub kernel and the ebd kernel.

This is how the **file jhub.yml** looks like:

```
name: jhub
channels:
- conda-forge
- defaults
dependencies:
- nb_conda_kernels
- jupyter
- jupyterlab
- jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
- ipyleaflet
- ipykernel
- ipywidgets
- jupyter-server-proxy
- nodejs
```

This is how the **file ebd.yml** looks like:

```
name: ebd
channels:
- conda-forge
dependencies:
- python
- cartopy
- dask
- datashader
- descartes
- erddapy
- ffmpeg
- fsspec
- gdal
- gcsfs
- geolinks
- geopandas
- geoviews
- graphviz
- hdf4
- hdf5
- h5netcdf
- h5py
- holoviews
- hvplot
- intake
- intake-geopandas
- intake-stac
- intake-xarray
- ipyleaflet
- ipykernel
- ipywidgets
- lz4
- matplotlib-base
- matplotlib
- metpy
- nb_conda_kernels
- nc-time-axis
- netcdf4
- nomkl
- numpy
- owslib
- pandas
- panel
- psycopg2
- rasterio
- requests
- s3fs
- sat-search
- sat-stac
- satpy
- scikit-image
- scikit-learn
- scipy
- statsmodels
- tornado
- utide
- xarray
- zarr
```

Overall, i must first create both jhub and ebd environments to start the Jupyter Lab server working on my local webbrowser.

## First issue when creating jhub environment with conda

When i ran the command `conda env create -f jhub.yml` it stayed in `Solving Environment` forever, as it can be seen in the picture below

I was then told to install mamba and create the environment using the mamba prompt.

## `EnvironmentNameNotFound` after creating the environment with mamba

I had an apparently troublesome environment creation for both the jhub and ebd kernel, as it will be described below. All in all,the machine cannot activate both conda environments by their names.

Tried to activate environments after creation of environments with

```
mamba env create -f jhub.yml
mamba env create -f ebd.yml
```

Then, i asked for the list of conda environments. Note that there are no names for the ones I just installed (ebd and jhub)
[Conda environments activation attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyu3p.png)

If you need to check what the issues in the environments installation are, ask me and i will illustrate them to you

Please, i need to know what is wrong so i can finally follow and succeed with the step of

> **Jupyter Notebook**
> To start the Jupyter Lab server working on your local webbrowser, change to the root directory where you want to keep the notebooks (advanced users can change the default directory for notebooks in a configuration file). Typically this would be YOUR-GIT-REPOSOTORY-ROOT-PATH